# Ansible build a variable taken from a value of each member of a group

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory like this:

```
[mygroup]
host01.example.com private_ip: 10.0.0.2
host02.example.com private_ip: 10.0.0.3
host03.example.com private_ip: 10.0.0.4
```

When configurations on the machines involved other members of the group, I always used the FQDN without issues, and I was able to build a variable like:

```
{{ groups.mygroup | list | join(',') }}
```

that produce something like:

```
host01.example.com,host02.example.com,host03.example.com
```

Now I want to have something (built on private_ip variable) that looks like:

```
10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3,10.0.0.4
```

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the [INI](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#defining-variables-in-ini-format) format of the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[mygroup]
host01.example.com private_ip=10.0.0.2
host02.example.com private_ip=10.0.0.3
host03.example.com private_ip=10.0.0.4
```

[extract](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the variables *private_ip* from *hostvars*

```yaml
  private_ips: "{{ groups.mygroup|
                   map('extract', hostvars, 'private_ip')|join(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  private_ips: 10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3,10.0.0.4
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_hosts: "{{ groups.mygroup|join(',') }}"
    private_ips: "{{ groups.mygroup|
                     map('extract', hostvars, 'private_ip')|join(',') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_hosts
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: private_ips
      run_once: true
```